# Updated knitr function has changed the rmarkdown output from a list of values to showing the list code

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I have a report that compiles two values - items and vendors.  The previous iteration of `knitr` (1.16) output the `kable` table into the pdf and HTML documents as expected, however the updated version outputs the list *code*, rather than the list *values*.

```
    vTable <- structure(list(Item = c("Item 4", "Item C", "Item_A", "Item_B", 
"Item_B_raw"), Vendors = structure(list(`1` = c("Vendor 3", "Vendor_1", 
"Vendor_2", "Vendor4"), `2` = c("Vendor4", "Vendor 3", "Vendor_2", 
"Vendor_1", "Vendor 5."), `3` = c("Vendor 5.", "Vendor4", "Vendor_2"
), `4` = c("Vendor_1", "Vendor4", "Vendor 5."), `5` = c("Vendor_2", 
"Vendor 5.", "Vendor4", "Vendor 3")), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))), .Names = c("Item", "Vendors"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

vtable
            Item                                          Vendors
1     Item 4            Vendor 3, Vendor_1, Vendor_2, Vendor4
2     Item C Vendor4, Vendor 3, Vendor_2, Vendor_1, Vendor 5.
3     Item_A                     Vendor 5., Vendor4, Vendor_2
4     Item_B                     Vendor_1, Vendor4, Vendor 5.
5 Item_B_raw           Vendor_2, Vendor 5., Vendor4, Vendor 3
```

Using knitr_1.6,

```
kable(vTable)
|Item       |Vendors                                          |
|:----------|:------------------------------------------------|
|Item 4     |Vendor 3, Vendor_1, Vendor_2, Vendor4            |
|Item C     |Vendor4, Vendor 3, Vendor_2, Vendor_1, Vendor 5. |
|Item_A     |Vendor 5., Vendor4, Vendor_2                     |
|Item_B     |Vendor_1, Vendor4, Vendor 5.                     |
|Item_B_raw |Vendor_2, Vendor 5., Vendor4, Vendor 3           |
```

but the output for the current iteration of knitr_1.20:

```
kable(vTable)
|Item       |Vendors                                                       |
|:----------|:-------------------------------------------------------------|
|Item 4     |c("Vendor 3", "Vendor_1", "Vendor_2", "Vendor4")              |
|Item C     |c("Vendor4", "Vendor 3", "Vendor_2", "Vendor_1", "Vendor 5.") |
|Item_A     |c("Vendor 5.", "Vendor4", "Vendor_2")                         |
|Item_B     |c("Vendor_1", "Vendor4", "Vendor 5.")                         |
|Item_B_raw |c("Vendor_2", "Vendor 5.", "Vendor4", "Vendor 3")             |
```

I pasted the kable_1.6 function into an r script, moved it over to the new hardware, assigned it to "my_kable", but it returned `Error in pandoc_to() : could not find function "pandoc_to"`. I tried editing the function directly, to remove `x = replace_na(to_character(as.matrix(x)), is.na(x))` and paste the previous line `x = replace_na(base::format(as.matrix(x), trim = TRUE, justify = "none"), is.na(x))` to see if that was the offending bit, but continued to have the pandoc_to error.

- How do I adjust my data.frame code to correct this?
- Where am I going off the rails in editing the function?

Comment: Just coerce the list column to a formatted character vector for presentation purposes, e.g. `df$Vendors <- sapply(df$Vendors, toString)`

Comment: That definitely works. Obvious in hindsight, but I still found myself having to ask. Thank you.